# Fetch Specific text between a recurring pattern in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, replace, sql-server-2012, substring

I have a string, say the one like below,

```
@Text = ';AB =>ABX1;BC =>BXC2; CD =>CXD3;'
```

Now I need to reduce it down to this,

```
@Result = 'ABX1;BXC2;CXD3;'
```

So ultimately I need to remove everything between `';'` and `'=>'` or replace it with `''`

Is there a way to achieve this in SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 0):

Using one of the split strings from [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
declare @txt varchar(max)=';AB =>ABX1;BC =>BXC2; CD =>CXD3;';

;With cte
as
(select * from [dbo].[SplitStrings_Numbers](replace(@txt,'=>',''),';')
)
select 
stuff(
(select ';'+right(item,4) from cte c
where len(item)>0
for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```